# How to have a mdl badge for multiple rows in a table?

Tags: angular, angular2-mdl

I would like to make a mdl badge for mutliple lines in table row.
Ex: 1st row badge shows the result of a function,
2nd row show another result of the same function ...

Any idea on how to deal with this ?

Thanks!!

Comment: What have you got so far? It sounds like just nested directives

Comment: For the moment I have not done anything as I am just working on an angular service to get the data. i do not want it to be managed by the component itself. I have to write the function to count the number to show in the badge and add it as a property to the model that will be shown using the component.

Comment: we can't help you until you have work to show.